# Run on specific date a Python code that get data from internet and send to SQL DB

Tags: python, sql, events, task, scheduler

All,

I have a Python code getting monthly data from a data provider through its API, formatting them, and sending them to a SQL DB (I'm using SQL Studio, all is local).
The monthly data are roughly available 12-14 days after the end of the month. So far I was changing the month in my Python code and running the code once new data were available (let say May 12th, I queried data for month = 5).

Is there a way to make all of this automatic? I m no software developer and it seems that I have 0 skills on that! Can I schedule some task in Python? or SQL Studio? or a third party software?

Some other providers can email me when new data are available, is there a way to get this email to start a code (I made a code to parse their website and download the desired file)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My  oppinion is that the best way is to use OS tools (like `crontab` in Linux) to schedule and start some `python myscript.py`